# How to get correct data from Active Directory for authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory, ldap

I have a client service solution containing a Winforms client application and a WCF service hosted in IIS.

At the WCF service I can easily extract the current user's name (`WindowsIdentity.Name`) that is logged on at the client by using a custom `IAuthorizationPolicy`. This is done by getting the `WindowsIdentity` from the incoming `EvaluationContext` in the Evaluate method.

The `WindowsIdentity.Name` will look something like this : `MyCompanyGroup\MyName`

To be able to bind to an AD account in my own membership model I need to be able to let the user choose an AD user to bind to on the Winforms client. To extract the AD groups and users for a tree I am using the following code:

```
public static class ActiveDirectoryHandler
{
  public static List<ActiveDirectoryTreeNode> GetGroups()
  {
    DirectoryEntry objADAM = default(DirectoryEntry);
    // Binding object. 
    DirectoryEntry objGroupEntry = default(DirectoryEntry);
    // Group Results. 
    DirectorySearcher objSearchADAM = default(DirectorySearcher);
    // Search object. 
    SearchResultCollection objSearchResults = default(SearchResultCollection);
    // Results collection. 
    string strPath = null;
    // Binding path. 
    List<ActiveDirectoryTreeNode> result = new List<ActiveDirectoryTreeNode>();

    // Construct the binding string. 
    strPath = "LDAP://stefanserver.stefannet.local";
    //Change to your ADserver 

    // Get the AD LDS object. 
    try
    {
        objADAM = new DirectoryEntry();//strPath);
        objADAM.RefreshCache();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    // Get search object, specify filter and scope, 
    // perform search. 
    try
    {
        objSearchADAM = new DirectorySearcher(objADAM);
        objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    // Enumerate groups 
    try
    {
        if (objSearchResults.Count != 0)
        {
            //SearchResult objResult = default(SearchResult);
            foreach (SearchResult objResult in objSearchResults)
            {
                objGroupEntry = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                result.Add(new ActiveDirectoryTreeNode() { Id = objGroupEntry.Guid, ParentId = objGroupEntry.Parent.Guid, Text = objGroupEntry.Name, Type = ActiveDirectoryType.Group, PickableNode = false });

                foreach (object child in objGroupEntry.Properties["member"])
                    result.Add(new ActiveDirectoryTreeNode() { Id= Guid.NewGuid(), ParentId = objGroupEntry.Guid, Text = child.ToString(), Type = ActiveDirectoryType.User, PickableNode = true });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No groups found");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }

    return result;
  } 
}

public class ActiveDirectoryTreeNode : ISearchable
{
    private Boolean _pickableNode = false;
#region Properties
[GenericTreeColumn(GenericTableDescriptionAttribute.MemberTypeEnum.TextBox, 0, VisibleInListMode = false, Editable = false)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
[GenericTreeColumn(GenericTableDescriptionAttribute.MemberTypeEnum.TextBox, 1, VisibleInListMode = false, Editable = false)]
public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
[GenericTreeColumn(GenericTableDescriptionAttribute.MemberTypeEnum.TextBox, 2, Editable = false)]
public string Text { get; set; }
public ActiveDirectoryType Type { get; set; }
#endregion

#region ISearchable
public string SearchString
{
    get { return Text.ToLower(); }
}

public bool PickableNode
{
    get { return _pickableNode; }
    set { _pickableNode = value; }
}
#endregion

}

public enum ActiveDirectoryType
{
    Group,
    User
}
```

The tree could look something like this :

```
CN=Users*
- CN=Domain Guests,CN=Users,DC=MyCompany,DC=local
- CN=5-1-5-11,CN=ForeignSecurityPrinipals,DC=MyCompany,DC=local
...
CN=Domain Admins
- CN=MyName,CN=Users,DC=MyCompany,DC=local
...
```

(* = Group)

The name is of a different format and I don't see how this could be compared to the name on the service.

So how do I extract proper Active Directory data for the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot claim to understand what it is that you are asking but here is some information that I hope you will find helpful.

The log in name that you see on your service (i.e. "MyName") corresponds to a property in the AD called `sAMAccountName`.  You can pull `sAMAccountName` from [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) through the [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties.aspx) collection.  For example if you want to show the `sAMAccountName` for each member of your group you can do the following:

```
var objSearchADAM = new DirectorySearcher();
objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
var objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult objResult in objSearchResults)
{
    using (var objGroupEntry = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry())
    {
        foreach (string child in objGroupEntry.Properties["member"])
        {
            var path = "LDAP://" + child.Replace("/", "\\/");
            using (var memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
            {
                if (memberEntry.Properties.Contains("sAMAccountName"))
                {
                    // Get sAMAccountName
                    string sAMAccountName = memberEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(sAMAccountName);
                }

                if (memberEntry.Properties.Contains("objectSid"))
                {
                    // Get objectSid
                    byte[] sidBytes = (byte[]) memberEntry.Properties["objectSid"][0];
                    var sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(sidBytes, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(sid.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might also find [`UserPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338505.aspx) interesting.  With this class you can very easily connect to a user object in your AD with the [`FindByIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) method as shown below:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);
using (var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "MyName"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(up.DistinguishedName);
    Console.WriteLine(up.SamAccountName);

    // Print groups that this user is a member of
    foreach (var group in up.GetGroups())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.SamAccountName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the first code gives me expcetion when trying to create the DirectoryEntry object : The value provided for adsObject does not implement IADs?

Comment: I changed to child.ToString() and then I got my drectoryEntry object but then I get thre an exception of type 'System.Runtim.InteropService.ComException' when trying to get the sAMAccountName?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in my code.  I forgot to add "LDAP://" to the member paths.  I updated my answer so please try my updated example code.

Comment: Thanks alot!but I do still not see how I could compare the memberEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0] to the windowsClient.Name(on the serivce). The windowsClient.Name is for example group\\myAccountName while the memberEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0] only gives me MyAccountName? And what if the user is moved to another group? Maby there is another identifier I could use to be sure that I got the correct user (where the group does not matther? From the WindowsClient object(service) I could get Token(1186) and User value(S-1-5-21-500572754-3590662030-3306607147-1189), could this be used?

Comment: The string "S1-5-21-...." corresponds to the objectSid property.  I updated my code once again to show how to retrieve this value.

Comment: Thanks! This is really greate, it works super and the second codpart did also come to use.